# How does gc work with eventlet(greenlet) in python?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, eventlet

I made a corolocal.local in the following test script, to find when an element in corolocal.local is got garbage collected. But it is still not very clear. The `TL.it` instantiated in the first thread is garbage collected when the second thread assign another value to it.
But I wander who did the gc.collect() at what time, is it related to 
the greenlet running scope? And i used to find `TL.it` is collected sometimes inside mainloop greenlet, sometimes another greenlet, which will cause problems inside my program. For example, if i do hub.switch() inside __del__() method, which will report error "Cannot switch to MAINLOOP from MAINLOOP".

```
import gc
import threading
from eventlet import hubs
from eventlet import event
import greenlet

import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch(all=True)


class InsideLocal(object):
    def __init__(self, td):
        self.td = td

    def __del__(self):
        print("Current greenlet inside %s: %s" %
              (self.td, greenlet.getcurrent()))
        print("Got deleted inside %s" % self.td)


class OutSideLocal(object):
    def __init__(self, td):
        self.td = td

    def __del__(self):
        print("Current greenlet outside %s: %s" %
              (self.td, greenlet.getcurrent()))
        print("Got deleted outside %s" % self.td)

TL = threading.local()


def play_insidethread(td, e):
    global TL
    TL.it = InsideLocal(td)
    ot = OutSideLocal(td)
    e.wait()
    print("Quiting thread %s" % td)

print("====Starting first thread====")
e = event.Event()
gt = eventlet.spawn(play_insidethread, 'first', e)

print("Primary greenlet: %s" % hubs.get_hub().greenlet)

# try to trigger gc for objects inside corolocal.local
# but here failed.
print("====Stopping first thread====")
e.send()
eventlet.sleep(0)

print("====Deleting greenthread object====")
# failed again
del gt
eventlet.sleep(0)

# failed again.
print("====Doing gc manually====")
print("gc %s" % gc.collect())
eventlet.sleep(0)

print("====Multi thread test====")
# succeeded.
events = []
for i in range(3):
    e = event.Event()
    events.append(e)
    eventlet.spawn(play_insidethread, i, e)

for e in events:
    e.send()
    eventlet.sleep(1)

print("====Quiting test====")
quit = event.Event()
quit.wait()
```

OUTPUT:

```
====Starting first thread====
Primary greenlet: <greenlet.greenlet object at 0x8c32d0>
====Stopping first thread====
Quiting thread first
Current greenlet outside first: <eventlet.greenthread.GreenThread object at 0x8c3370>
Got deleted outside first
====Deleting greenthread object====
====Doing gc manually====
gc 0
====Multi thread test====
Current greenlet inside first: <eventlet.greenthread.GreenThread object at 0x8c3370>
Got deleted inside first
Quiting thread 0
Current greenlet outside 0: <eventlet.greenthread.GreenThread object at 0x8c3370>
Got deleted outside 0
Current greenlet inside 0: <eventlet.greenthread.GreenThread object at 0x8c3410>
Got deleted inside 0
Quiting thread 1
Current greenlet outside 1: <eventlet.greenthread.GreenThread object at 0x8c3410>
Got deleted outside 1
Current greenlet inside 1: <greenlet.greenlet object at 0x8c32d0>
Got deleted inside 1
Quiting thread 2
Current greenlet outside 2: <eventlet.greenthread.GreenThread object at 0x8c34b0>
Got deleted outside 2
====Quiting test====
```

EDIT:

I have read [this article](https://www.quora.com/How-does-garbage-collection-in-Python-work), but i didn't get an answer. According to what was said in that article, every time one object is accessed(create, delete, eg), python interpreter will try to do garbage collection once, and delete some objects from memory if necessary. This can't explain my test result, which in fact  objects in threading.local() and not in threading.local() behave differently. Objects not in threading.local() never got deleted when  mainloop is running, but objects in threading.local() do.

Comment: The garbage collection is done automatically by the interpreter. It removes objects to which there are not references anymore. If you want to keep an object, keep a reference (a variable) pointing to it. More details can be found at https://www.quora.com/How-does-garbage-collection-in-Python-work

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you for the useful information. But that's not enough. I have read that article, and updated the question.